# Problem with my conditions in Java

Tags: java, swing

good day...

i have a problem in searching my entries in my addressbook program... i already search them... but i'm having problem with showing the "Name not found!" message if the name is not yet saved in my addressbook.  Can you help me figure out what's wrong with this...

```
public void searchEntry() {

    int notfound = 0;
    SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to find: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, entry[i].getInfo2());
        }else{
            notfound++;
        }

        if (notfound != 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me show the "Name not found" msg... thnx in advance

Comment: You say you're "having problems" showing it - what problems? What's currently happening?

Comment: You should rather count the `found` rows. And, outside the `for` loop, test `if (found == 0) { display "Not found"; }

Comment: The main problem is inattention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move this:

```
if (notfound != 0){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
}
```

outside your for loop.

I also just realized that you're probably going to have this shown up for every single one, because you're triggering even if it's not found once. Try something like this:

```
SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to find: ");
boolean found = false;
Object info;
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
  if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
    found = true;
    info = entry[i].getInfo2();
    break;
  }
}
if (found){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, info);
}else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
}
```

Comment: ... and make it support the case when `entry[]` is empty. Why not just boolean?

Comment: @kylar yes... this shows the "Name not Found!" msg.. but it was also shown even if the name i entered has already found.. it shows first the details but then still see the "Name not Found!" msg... please help thanks a lot...

Comment: @konrad, i am still new at java.. and not familiar with the boolean... :(

Comment: Is that just when you move it out, or when you add in my other refactor?

Comment: can i ask a little more favor.. can you help me figure out what to do instead of doing the code i posted here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043686/how-to-delete-entry-in-an-address-book-program-using-java/5043732#5043732

Answer (score 1):

```
public void searchEntry() {
    boolean isFind = false;
    SName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name to find: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        if (SName.equals(entry[i].getName())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, entry[i].getInfo2());
            isFind  = true;
            break; // TODO: I think if you find name you should leave loop.
        }
    }
if (isFind){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is quite flawed.  It seems you want to iterate over some collection of people, do a name compare and when you find someone, you want a message with string X and when you don't find any, you want a message with string Y.   That being said, you should probably want to put the message handling outside the loop and have a String to store the found name and use that for the conditionalizer.  Here is an example:

```
String  nameFound = null;

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    if (entry[i].getName().equals(SName)) {
        nameFound = entry[i].getInfo2();
        break; // Stop looking since you found the person
    }
}

if (nameFound != null){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nameFound);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Not Found!");
}
```

Comment: thnx jeremy.. break makes it run properly :)